# Apple push notifications without developer account

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

I know, It's necessary to have enrolled Apple Developer account to work on push notifications? 
Is it possible for someone else, who already have dev. account to generate the certificate for me, or it's restricted by Apple?

Answer (score 4):

Not as far as I know and I've been building mobile apps for five years now. You need to have your own account set up, even if you're using a third party solution like Firebase Cloud Messaging. You'd also need that to publish the app to the iOS app store.

If someone else was publishing the app on your behalf, they could do it for you.

Comment: Thanks Matthew.
As I know, It's possible to test push notifications without publishing the app on the Appstore and for this you just need production certificate.
So, If someone else generates for me this kind of certificate, can I use it?

Comment: The problem is you can't install a development build on your own device unless you register its UDID, which requires a developer account. Otherwise the app simply can't be installed.

Comment: @ikajava You can't. Even if someone create a certificate for you and also add your device UDID. Still you required a Apple developer account to select a development team to run app on your device, as per current XCode requirement.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have enrolled payed account already. 
Thanks a lot.